# change css property of elements if they are 300px from top of the viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, viewport

hi i don't know javascript, but i tryied to write this...this changes the properties of an element...based on the position in which it is relative to the window of the broswer....scilicet the viewport.

it took me two days and now it work, BUT just for an element,cuz you can use just an ID, i would like it to work for all the elements with the same class.

each elements must be autonomous, so they do not have to influence each other.

for example if the element called Primo is in a certain position, it must only modify it's rotation 
and in the same way if the element called Secondo is in a certain position, it must only modify it's rotation 
thanks in advance for the help

```js
function getViewportOffset($e) {
  var $window = $(window),
    scrollLeft = $window.scrollLeft(),
    scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
    offset = $e.offset(),
    rect1 = { x1: scrollLeft, y1: scrollTop, x2: scrollLeft + $window.width(), y2: scrollTop + $window.height() },
    rect2 = { x1: offset.left, y1: offset.top, x2: offset.left + $e.width(), y2: offset.top + $e.height() };
  return {
    left: offset.left - scrollLeft,
    top: offset.top - scrollTop,
    insideViewport: rect1.x1 < rect2.x2 && rect1.x2 > rect2.x1 && rect1.y1 < rect2.y2 && rect1.y2 > rect2.y1
  };
}
$(window).on("load scroll resize", function() {
  var viewportOffset = getViewportOffset ($("#primo"));
  var valueprimo = viewportOffset.top - 350;
      if  (viewportOffset.top < 130)  {
        document.getElementById("primo").style.transform = "rotatez(-55deg) rotate(-45deg)  translate(0,0)";
    } else if (viewportOffset.top > 343) {
        document.getElementById("primo").style.transform = "rotatez(0deg) rotate(-45deg)  translate(0,0)";
    } else if (viewportOffset.top > 130) {
        document.getElementById("primo").style.transform = "rotatez(" + valueprimo / 4 + "deg) rotate(-45deg)  translate(0,0)";
    }
});
```

```css
body {height: 2048px}
.element {position: absolute;
  top: 400px; left: 30px;
  width: 107px;
  height:107px;
  background-color: #707070}
#secondo {position: absolute;
  top: 450px; left: 150px;
}
#terzo {position: absolute;
  top: 550px; left: 270px;
}
#quarto {position: absolute;
  top: 650px; left: 150px;
}
#quinto {position: absolute;
  top: 450px; left: 510px;
}
#sesto {position: absolute;
  top: 350px; left: 630px;
}
#settimo {position: absolute;
  top: 650px; left: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="primo" class="element" name="element"></div>
<div id="secondo" class="element" name="element"></div>
<div id="terzo" class="element" name="element"></div>
<div id="quarto" class="element" name="element"></div>
<div id="quinto" class="element" name="element"></div>
<div id="sesto" class="element" name="element"></div>
<div id="settimo" class="element" name="element"></div>

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `.each()` function as shown below:

```js
function getViewportOffset($e) {
  var $window = $(window),
      scrollLeft = $window.scrollLeft(),
      scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
      offset = $e.offset(),
      rect1 = { x1: scrollLeft, y1: scrollTop, x2: scrollLeft + $window.width(), y2: scrollTop + $window.height() },
      rect2 = { x1: offset.left, y1: offset.top, x2: offset.left + $e.width(), y2: offset.top + $e.height() };
  return {
    left: offset.left - scrollLeft,
    top: offset.top - scrollTop,
    insideViewport: rect1.x1 < rect2.x2 && rect1.x2 > rect2.x1 && rect1.y1 < rect2.y2 && rect1.y2 > rect2.y1
  };
}
$(window).on("load scroll resize", function() {
    $(".element").each(function(){
          var viewportOffset = getViewportOffset ($(this));
          var valueprimo = viewportOffset.top - 350;
          if  (viewportOffset.top < 130)  {
             $(this).css("transform", "rotatez(-55deg) rotate(-45deg)  translate(0,0)");
          } 
          else if (viewportOffset.top > 343) {
                $(this).css("transform", "rotatez(0deg) rotate(-45deg)  translate(0,0)");
          } 
          else if (viewportOffset.top > 130) {
                $(this).css("transform", "rotatez(" + valueprimo / 4 + "deg) rotate(-45deg)) translate(0,0)");
          }
    });
});
```

```css
body {height: 2048px}
.element {position: absolute;
  top: 400px; left: 30px;
  width: 107px;
  height:107px;
  background-color: #707070}
#secondo {position: absolute;
  top: 450px; left: 150px;
}
#terzo {position: absolute;
  top: 550px; left: 270px;
}
#quarto {position: absolute;
  top: 650px; left: 150px;
}
#quinto {position: absolute;
  top: 450px; left: 510px;
}
#sesto {position: absolute;
  top: 350px; left: 630px;
}
#settimo {position: absolute;
  top: 650px; left: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="primo" class="element" name="element"></div>
<div id="secondo" class="element" name="element"></div>
<div id="terzo" class="element" name="element"></div>
<div id="quarto" class="element" name="element"></div>
<div id="quinto" class="element" name="element"></div>
<div id="sesto" class="element" name="element"></div>
<div id="settimo" class="element" name="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the IDs of the elements to be animated on scrolling, their lower/upper scroll positions to start/stop animation, the initial/final values of the animated property and the information which property to animate for it in an array or object, and then loop through it, e.g. like this:

```js
var settings = {
   primo: {
      minTop: 130,
      maxTop: 350,
      // animates rotation from -55 deg to 0
      valAtMin: -55,
      valAtMax: 0,
      transformTemplate: "rotatez({X}deg) rotate(-45deg)  translate(0,0)"
   },
   secondo: {
      minTop: 20,
      maxTop: 160,
      // animates rotation from 175 deg to -30deg
      valAtMin: 175,
      valAtMax: -30,
      transformTemplate: "rotatez({X}deg) rotate(-45deg)  translate(0,0)"
   },
   terzo: {
      minTop: 50,
      maxTop: 180,
      // this time, animates the horizontal shift from 0 to 90px
      valAtMin: 0,
      valAtMax: 90,
      transformTemplate: "rotate(-45deg) translate({X}px,0)"
   }
}

// no need to redefine this on each call
var $window = $(window);
 
function getViewportOffset($e) {
  var scrollLeft = $window.scrollLeft(),
      scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
      offset = $e.offset(),
      rect1 = { x1: scrollLeft, y1: scrollTop, x2: scrollLeft + $window.width(), y2: scrollTop + $window.height() },
      rect2 = { x1: offset.left, y1: offset.top, x2: offset.left + $e.width(), y2: offset.top + $e.height() };
  return {
    left: offset.left - scrollLeft,
    top: offset.top - scrollTop,
    insideViewport: rect1.x1 < rect2.x2 && rect1.x2 > rect2.x1 && rect1.y1 < rect2.y2 && rect1.y2 > rect2.y1
  };
}

$(window).on("load scroll resize", function() {
   for (var id in settings) {
      var elem = $('#'+id);
      if (!elem) continue; // skip if element with this id doesn't exist
      var elemSettings = settings[id];
      var offsetTop = getViewportOffset(elem).top;
      var value;
      // calculate the value proportionally to scrolling position between limits
      if (offsetTop <= elemSettings.minTop) value = elemSettings.valAtMin;
      else if (offsetTop >= elemSettings.maxTop) value = elemSettings.valAtMax;
      else value = elemSettings.valAtMin + (elemSettings.valAtMax - elemSettings.valAtMin) * (offsetTop - elemSettings.minTop) / (elemSettings.maxTop - elemSettings.minTop);
      // store the current value in the same object
      elemSettings.value = value;
   }

   // if this is the first call, start the animation 
   if (!animationStarted) requestAnimationFrame(doAnimation);     
});

// a small performance optimization:
// use requestAnimationFrame for animation to avoid too frequent redrawings
function doAnimation() {
   for (var id in settings) {
      var elem = $('#'+id);
      if (!elem) continue; // skip if element with this id doesn't exist
      var elemSettings = settings[id];
      elem.css('transform', elemSettings.transformTemplate.replace('{X}', elemSettings.value));
   }
   requestAnimationFrame(doAnimation);
}

animationStarted = false;
```

```css
body {height: 2048px}
.element {position: absolute;
  top: 400px; left: 30px;
  width: 107px;
  height:107px;
  background-color: #707070}
#secondo {position: absolute;
  top: 450px; left: 150px;
}
#terzo {position: absolute;
  top: 550px; left: 270px;
}
#quarto {position: absolute;
  top: 650px; left: 150px;
}
#quinto {position: absolute;
  top: 450px; left: 510px;
}
#sesto {position: absolute;
  top: 350px; left: 630px;
}
#settimo {position: absolute;
  top: 650px; left: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="primo" class="element" name="element"></div>
<div id="secondo" class="element" name="element"></div>
<div id="terzo" class="element" name="element"></div>
<div id="quarto" class="element" name="element"></div>
<div id="quinto" class="element" name="element"></div>
<div id="sesto" class="element" name="element"></div>
<div id="settimo" class="element" name="element"></div>
```